# How can I install ruby 1.8.7?

Tags: 12.10, ruby, fedena

I am not ruby guy, but I have good experience with apache and php, but I find it really difficult to setup ruby 1.8.7, cause I find a lot of ways to do the same and I am pretty much confused. I want to install open source project management system fedena in ubuntu 12.10 which required ruby 1.8.7 to run.

Comment: You should look at `rvm`

Comment: I assume you looked into the fedena docs already, right?

Comment: yes fedena docs for installation is not good for setting up a production environment in a vps. Its really really slow if I set it up in that way .

Comment: i saw rvm but is there any another apt-get method ?

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 12.10 the [ruby1.8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/ruby1.8) package gives you `ruby 1.8.7-p358`. The binary it installs is compatible with fedena.

I would also suggest looking into something like [rvm](https://rvm.io/) in order to maintain different versions of rubies. If you don't need something quite as heavy as rvm you could try [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) which is a similar idea but allows you to install rubies using the [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) plugin or any other method you choose such as source or apt-get.  It just makes sure that your projects use the ruby you want it to using a file in the source directory.  If you want to go even lighter weight than rbenv there is one more potential alternative you can check out called [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). It is a similar idea to rbenv but implements it in a slightly different way.

My first suggestion is the only pure apt-get solution but I would suggest using at least chruby to make sure projects use the correct ruby once you have multiple installed.

Edit:

See @berkes comment about using symlinks for default ruby. If you don't like rbenv, rvm, or chruby it can be a great alternative allowing you to quickly change the system rubies.  The command `update-alternatives` is a great way to automate this process. Add an alternative using the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set ruby /path/to/ruby
```

You can also check which alternatives are configured and selected using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config ruby
```

Comment: In addition to the excellent advice from @Danny Dyla, when you apt-get install different versions of Ruby, you can find their binaries in your path: `ruby1.8.7`  under `/usr/bin/ruby*`. `/usr/bin/ruby` is then a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/ruby` which, again, is a symlink to your systems default. E.g.: `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`